# Can i implement Spring Session without Spring Security?

Tags: spring-security, spring-session

Can i manage the complete HTTPSession lifecycle (Creation, Update, Destroy and Expiry) only with Spring Session and without using Spring Security ?

Reason i got this question is that, Spring Security states that it provides 'Session Auto-Expiry' & 'Concurrent Session' features. Wouldn't 'Session Auto-Expiry' be available in 'Spring Session' itself ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe so. The [Multiple Users](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/users.html) sample demonstrates login/logout without using Spring Security.

In this case Session auto expiry is provided by the Redis backend.